# Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, imagen

**¿Por qué motivo me muestra el error: Array to string conversion?**

Si únicamente le paso un valor a la función `anadirImagenAccesorio`, y ese valor es un texto.

**Código PHP:**

```
static public function anadirImagenAccesorio ($descripcion) {

    $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO accesorios (descripcion) VALUES (UPPER('" . $descripcion . "'))";
    $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);

    if ($ok == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Código HTML + PHP:**

```
<!-- Añadir un accesorio -->
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="anadir_accesorio" id="anadir_accesorio" method="POST">
    <!-- Subir archivo -->
    <label for="accesorio">Accesorio:</label>
    <input type="file" name="accesorio" id="accesorio" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Subir" id="guardar_accesorio" name="guardar_accesorio" />
</form>

//Si pulsamos el botón "Guardar accesorio"... 
if (isset($_POST["guardar_accesorio"])) {

    //Subir el nombre de una imagen. $_FILES: Variables de subida de ficheros HTTP.
    if (!isset($_FILES["accesorio"]) || $_FILES["accesorio"]["error"] > 0) {

        echo "Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo...";

    } else {

        //Comprobamos si la extensión el fichero es de tipo imagen y menor de 16MB.
        $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
        $limite_kb = 16384;

        //Si la extensión del fichero a subir, coincide con la de permitidos...
        if (in_array($_FILES['accesorio']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['accesorio']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {

            //Guardamos la imagen como archivo local en "$imagen_temporal". [tmp_name] sería para archivo temporal (carpeta tmp de Xampp).
            $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['accesorio']['name'];
            //Tipo de extensión.
            $tipo = $_FILES['accesorio']['type'];

            //Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la base de datos correctamente.
            $imagen = $imagen_temporal;

            //Explode(): divide un string en varios string.
            $nombre_accesorio = explode(".", $imagen);

            //Insertamos en la base de datos.
            $sql = BD::anadirImagenAccesorio($nombre_accesorio);

        } else {

            echo "Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño límite de $limite_kb Kbytes.";

        }

    }

}
```

He de añadir que la tabla accesorios dispone de dos campos: `idaccesorio` (auto_increment - int) y `descripcion` (string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque estás concatenando un array y eso no se puede hacer.

Aquí declaras `$nombre_accesorio` como array

```
//Explode(): divide un string en varios string.
                $nombre_accesorio = explode(".", $imagen);
```

Aquí lo pasas como parámetro

```
//Insertamos en la base de datos.
            $sql = BD::anadirImagenAccesorio($nombre_accesorio);
```

Y aquí lo intentas concatenar, cosa que no se puede hacer.

```
static public function anadirImagenAccesorio($descripcion){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO accesorios (descripcion) VALUES (UPPER('".$descripcion."'))";//aquí
        ...
    }
```

Comment: ¿$nombre_accesorio es un array? Simplemente es la división de un string, es decir, otro string. Y como tal, lo trato como si fuera un único elemento. ¿Por qué me lo detecta como "array"?

Comment: @omaza1990, consulta la documentación de [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), esta función devuelve un `Array`.

Comment: Lee la documentación de explode, lo que hace es convertir un texto a array separado por el delimitador, ejemplo$nombre_accesorio = "hola, como, estas";, si tu haces explode a esa cadena explode(',', $nombre_accesorio); te regresara ['hola', 'como', 'estas'], si quieres comprobar has un print_r a la variable

documentación de explode http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Comment: Cierto, con incluir únicamente la posición [0] del array era válido. Gracias.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es para qué usas `explode`, si en la pregunta dices que quieres insertar un valor. Como se ha dicho en comentarios, `explode` crea un array, separando los elementos por el caracter indicado. Si tú haces un `print_r($nombre_accesorio);` verás que en efecto hay un array con diferentes elementos. Y si tú haces `echo $nombre_accesorio;` verás que lo que te imprime es `Array` y te advertirá: `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion...` Ese error significa que estás tratando un array como una cadena. Entonces, **¿por qué haces `explode`?**, ¡that's the question!